# Photo Album in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0, asp.net-2.0

i am working visual studio 2008 with database as sql server 2005
i need to create a photo album 
i used listview control to display data

my table contains :>
Email_Id 
title 
description 
Image

i used generic handler to convert binary data into image

now the main problem is when i upload photo it is uploaded to my database properly 
but when i try to display the image 
the first image with Email_Id is only shown in listview controls

```
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" GroupItemCount="4" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="Email_Id">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:Placeholder
                        id="groupPlaceholder"
                        runat="server" />
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <div>
                        <asp:Placeholder
                        id="itemPlaceholder"
                        runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="font-size:medium;">
          <asp:Image id="picAlbum" runat="server" width="150px" Height="200px"
             ImageUrl='<%# "~/PHandler.ashx?Email_Id=" + Eval("Email_Id") %>' />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyItemTemplate>            

                    </EmptyItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
```

" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT [Email_Id], [Title], [Description], [Image] FROM [Picture_album] WHERE ([Email_Id] = @Email_Id)">

> can any one help me out 
>   i want to show all the image uploaded by the specific email_id in my photo ablum

Comment: What's the primary key field of the table? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: no primary key is there in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phandler.ashx is only getting email_id.  You will need to give it more to know which image to load.  Alter your table to include a uniqueiidentifier or timestamp field and pass that to you handler instead.  Also you should not be selecting the image field from this page as the handler should be doing that.

Comment: any examples that can help me out

Comment: sorry no.  try doing what I outlined above and let me know where you get hung up.